# Running gradle build from a parent folder

Tags: java, gradle

I have a folder structure:

```
- sam-wrapper/  
-- issuing/
--- build.gradle
--- gradlew
```

So when I navigate to the `issuing` folder and run `./gradlew build` it works fine.

But when I go out into the `sam-wrapper` folder and run `issuing/./gradlew build` I get the errors:

```
classpath
No dependencies
```

And when I run `issuing/./gradlew integrationTest` I see errors:

```
Task 'integrationTest' not found in root project 'sam-issuing'
```

What is the correct command to run gradle build within the parent folder (`sam-wrapper`)?

**EDIT**

`sam-wrapper` is just the parent directory, the gradle project is within `issuing`

Comment: It isn't clear if `issuing` is a subproject in a multiproject build or not but if it is, you should be able to `./gradlew issuing:integrationTest`.

Comment: The `-p` Option specifies ‘working directory’ for gradle. So something like `./childDir/gradlew -p ./childDir build` or similar. (If it’s a multi project build see comment above.)

Comment: issuing is the gradle project, its within the parent directory /sam-wrapper/

Answer (score 2):

as @BeUndead suggested use `-p` option.

`./issuing/gradlew -p ./issuing build`